# Where did my Mouse Droid pet go?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I got my Mouse Droid from the mail and clicked on it, which gave me some message about adding a pet.  It followed me for a while but disappeared at some point, and it's no longer in my inventory or anywhere else I've checked.  How can I get it back?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears in your Abilities list (press P to open) on the Pets tab.  Its name is [Minimech CE](http://www.torhead.com/item/6BQ54EU).